# How do I insert different list slice in "for loop"?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, slice

I am trying to create a dictionary for each row, column and field for numpy array, size 9x9. (Like in sudoku game) To be able to see if there are no duplicates. Everything works fine but I wonder if it is possible to create  `field_dic` in a loop?:

```
sudoku =[]  # Some 9x9 numpy.ndarray

row_dic = {}
col_dic = {}
field_dic = {}


for i in range(9):
    col_dic[f"Row{i}"] = dict(Counter(sudoku[:, i]))
    row_dic[f"Col{i}"] = dict(Counter(sudoku[i, :]))

field_dic = {
    "Field0": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[:3, :3].flat))),
    "Field1": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[:3, 3:6].flat))),
    "Field2": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[:3, 6:].flat))),
    "Field3": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[3:6, :3].flat))),
    "Field4": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[3:6, 3:6].flat))),
    "Field5": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[3:6, 6:].flat))),
    "Field6": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[6:, :3].flat))),
    "Field7": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[6:, 3:6].flat))),
    "Field8": dict(Counter(list(sudoku[6:, 6:].flat)))}
```

Comment: One extra trick, flatten the 2D blocks by using `.reshape(9)`. Then the blocks will behave just like the rows and cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran reshape the original array from `(9,9)` to `(3,3,3,3)`. Then the dimension `0` of the reshaped array will give you the row and dimension `2` will give you the column position of your block.

```
import numpy as np

sample = np.arange(81).reshape((9,9))
reshaped = sample.reshape(3,3,3,3)

field_dic = {}
for i in range(9):
    field_dic[f"Field{i}"] = reshaped[(i//3),:,i%3,:].reshape(9)
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> print('first block:\n', reshaped[0,:,0,:])
 first block:
 [[ 0  1  2]
  [ 9 10 11]
  [18 19 20]]

>>> print(field_dic['Field0'])
[ 0  1  2  9 10 11 18 19 20]

>>> print(field_dic['Field1'])
[ 3  4  5 12 13 14 21 22 23]

>>> print(field_dic['Field3'])
[27 28 29 36 37 38 45 46 47]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop, but dict comprehension might be a better choice.

To give you a head start:

```python
import itertools

ind_groups = [(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9)]
field_positions = itertools.product(ind_groups, ind_groups)
field_dict = {
  f'Field{i}': (r0, r1, c0, c1) for (i, ((r0, r1), (c0, c1))) in enumerate(field_positions)
}
```